# Can vision.cascadeObjectDetector calculate HOG, LBP features given a cascade.xml?

Tags: matlab, opencv, matlab-cvst, cascade-classifier

I have created a cascade.xml for detecting face images using the opencv_traincascade utility. I am using LBP or HOG feature based cascades since they are much faster. And I do all my testing on Matlab using `vision.cascadeObjectDetector`. But I am unsure if Matlab is capable of understanding and calculating LBP/ HOG features for a given cascade.xml file.

Is this the correct approach for testing a cascade detector? If not, what platform should I be using for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `vision.cascadeObjectDetector` supports LBP and HOG, as well as Haar features, as of version R2013a.

Furthermore you can now train your detector using `trainCascadeObjectDetector` function, which is easier to use than `opencv_traincascade`.  There is also a `trainingImageLabeler` app, which gives you a nice GUI to label objects of interest in your images.